# UIImage with alpha produces White Image

Tags: ios, uiimage, alpha

I have below block of code to apply alpha on UIImage,

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, self.scale);
[self drawAtPoint:CGPointZero blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:alpha];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Following is the *original Image before alpha being applied*:
[image: original Image before alpha being applied]

But after applying alpha with the above mentioned code it resulted in the following image(*alpha applied with value `0.6`*):
[image: Image after alpha applied - 0.6]

I supposed to receive a transparent image instead image is getting whitened as i keep apply alpha, If i apply an alpha of 0.0 the resulted image was a pure white image, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: in the imageView where you draw the image, set `imageView.backgroundColor = .clear`

Comment: @milan i know your suggestion but I need to generate the image with varied alpha values and upload it to server to consume it on web. During this I’m facing this issue.

Comment: show more context.. what is the code of the self? I would say it is the problem of drawing the context

Comment: Self here refers to image itself, it’s an UIImage category function which has the same code that I posted.

Comment: Bug reported to apple - https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=38250564 and it seems to be fix is available in iOS 12 Beta not tested myself though.